# Chalkboard shower surround?

Tags: shower

I have enough slate chalkboard from an old school to make a shower surround.  Support is not a problem, heavily reinforced concrete floors, cast iron tub with tile lip.  Need advice on adhesive and what to grout to use.  The pieces are 3 x 5 so will have seams.

Answer (score 1):

Slate is very porous, so however you install it, note that you're going to have to seal it well before it will be practical as a shower surround. As for grout, I'd use standard grout for shower tiles (as that's essentially what you are installing). Standard thinset should work for installing it on the wall.

Comment: Thanks, never worked with slate before although I have done tile tub surrounds and heated tile floors.